# I have tried CASE WHEN inside MATCH() but it give syntax error

Tags: php, mysql

```
 SELECT    products_description.products_title,
          product_settings.setting_value,
          products_description.product_description,
          products_description.long_description,
          products_additional_option_description.title,
          products_sizes.size_title,
          product_category_description.category_name,
          products.products_id,
          products_description.imagename,
          Match (products_description.products_title) against ('bu*'          IN boolean mode) AS rel_products_description_products_title,
          match (products_description.product_description) against ('bu*'     IN boolean mode) AS rel_products_description_product_description,
          match (products_description.long_description) against ('bu*'        IN boolean mode) AS rel_products_description_long_description,
          match (product_settings.setting_value) against ('bu*'               IN boolean mode) AS rel_product_settings_setting_value,
          match (products_additional_option_description.title) against ('bu*' IN boolean mode) AS rel_products_additional_option_description_title,
          match (products_sizes.size_title) against ('bu*'                    IN boolean mode) AS rel_products_sizes_size_title,
          match (product_category_description.category_name) against ('bu*'   IN boolean mode) AS rel_product_category_description_category_name ,
          CASE
                    WHEN store_products_description.products_title IS NOT NULL
                    AND       store_products_description.products_title!='' THEN store_products_description.products_title
                    ELSE products_description.products_title
          END AS products_title,
          CASE
                    WHEN store_products_description.product_description IS NOT NULL
                    AND       store_products_description.product_description!='' THEN store_products_description.product_description
                    ELSE products_description.product_description
          END AS product_description,
          CASE
                    WHEN store_products_description.long_description IS NOT NULL
                    AND       store_products_description.long_description!='' THEN store_products_description.long_description
                    ELSE products_description.long_description
          END AS long_description ,
          store_products.store_products_id
FROM      products
LEFT JOIN products_description
ON        products_description.products_id = products.products_id
LEFT JOIN store_products
ON        store_products.products_id = products.products_id
LEFT JOIN store_products_description
ON        store_products.store_products_id = store_products_description.store_products_id
AND       products_description.site_language_id = store_products_description.site_language_id
LEFT JOIN products_additional_option
ON        products_additional_option.products_id = products.products_id
LEFT JOIN products_additional_option_description
ON        products_additional_option_description.prod_add_opt_id = products_additional_option.prod_add_opt_id
LEFT JOIN product_settings
ON        product_settings.products_id = products.products_id
AND       product_settings.setting_constant_name = 'PRODUCT_SKU_NUMBER'
LEFT JOIN product_category
ON        product_category.category_id = products.category_id
LEFT JOIN product_category_description
ON        product_category.category_id = product_category_description.category_id
LEFT JOIN products_sizes
ON        products_sizes.products_id = products.products_id
WHERE     1
AND       products.visible = '1'
AND       store_products.visible = '1'
AND       products.products_id != '-11'
AND       (
                    store_products.user_type_id = '1'
          OR        store_products.user_type_id = '0' )
AND       products_description.site_language_id = '1'
AND       store_products_description.site_language_id = '1'
AND       (
                    match (
                    CASE
                              WHEN store_products_description.products_title IS NOT NULL
                              AND       store_products_description.products_title!='' THEN store_products_description.products_title
                              ELSE products_description.products_title
                    END AS products_title) against ('bu*' IN boolean mode)
          OR        match (
                    CASE
                              WHEN store_products_description.product_description IS NOT NULL
                              AND       store_products_description.product_description!='' THEN store_products_description.product_description
                              ELSE products_description.product_description
                    END AS product_description) against ('bu*' IN boolean mode)
          OR        match (
                    CASE
                              WHEN store_products_description.long_description IS NOT NULL
                              AND       store_products_description.long_description!='' THEN store_products_description.long_description
                              ELSE products_description.long_description
                    END AS long_description) against ('bu*'                             IN boolean mode)
          OR        match (product_settings.setting_value) against ('bu*'               IN boolean mode)
          OR        match (products_additional_option_description.title) against ('bu*' IN boolean mode)
          OR        match (products_sizes.size_title) against ('bu*'                    IN boolean mode)
          OR        match (product_category_description.category_name) against ('bu*'   IN boolean mode))
AND       store_products.store_id = '3'
GROUP BY  products.products_id
ORDER BY  (rel_products_description_products_title*7) +(rel_product_settings_setting_value*6) +(rel_products_description_product_description*5) +(rel_products_description_long_description*4) +(rel_products_additional_option_description_title*3) +(rel_products_sizes_size_title*2) +(rel_product_category_description_category_name*1) DESC
```

ERROR : #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(CASE WHEN store_products_description.products_tit' at line 65

Comment: I think there is a problem with the alias, you gave inside `match()`.Try without alias.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing identifiers and expressions.

[`MATCH()` takes a comma-separated list that names the columns to be searched](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-search.html).

`CASE WHEN expression THEN column` is an *expression* that returns the *value* of the column when the evaluated expression is true.

`MATCH()` looks like a function, but it is not evaluating the value of the column for each row, as it may appear to be doing.  It is using the column names as identifiers to pass to the fullest engine.

The logically correct way to write the query is inside-out relative to how it is written above:

```
WHERE ...
  AND CASE WHEN condition1 THEN MATCH(col1) AGAINST...
           WHEN condition 2 THEN MATCH(col2) AGAINST ...
           ELSE MATCH(col3) AGAINST ... END
 AND ...
```

In other words, when condition1 is true, the WHERE clause should evaluate the truthiness of whether the match against col1 was a hit, etc.

The `CASE` expression should then return true for each row based on the result of the appropriate match for that row, giving you the expected result.

I emphasize *"should."*

This is logically correct something of an off-label use of fulltext, and I have not had an opportunity to verify yet.  Because fulltext searches operate on the entire table, regardless, and require the server to filter out rows excluded by other predicates, the performance of such a query will be interesting, too.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing all match()

```
 match (CASE WHEN store_products_description.products_title IS NOT NULL
         AND store_products_description.products_title!='' THEN 
             store_products_description.products_title
        ELSE products_description.products_title
         END AS products_title) against ('bu*' IN boolean mode)
```

Using

```
match (CASE WHEN store_products_description.products_title IS NOT NULL
         AND store_products_description.products_title!='' THEN 
             store_products_description.products_title
        ELSE products_description.products_title
         END ) against ('bu*' IN boolean mode)
```

Giving alias inside `match()` may caused the problem.. Hope this helps